# Plot enum values in dataframe using pyplot segmented bar

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have a Series of (timestamp, enum value) describing when a system was in a given state; the state is described by the enum.

```
Time | State
--------------
  0  |   A
  3  |   B
  4  |   A
  7  |   C
  9  |   D
```

I'd like to visualize the state changes in a bar plot by filling each state forward to the next timestamp, and using a different color for each enum value:

```
|
|__________________________________________
|     A     | B |     A     |   C   |  D  |
|___________|___|___________|_______|_____|
|
---------------------------------------------
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
```

Any advice? I've looked into `Line Collection`s and horizontal bars, but Line Collections seem clunky and hbar seems to be for scalar values. I'm hoping to find an elegant idiomatic solution.

Comment: Why is `D` drawn until 10, BTW? How do you know how long it is?

Comment: That's just some arbitrary "rightmost value of the graph". In my real use-case I'm plotting lots of these bars, and filling forward the last value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create bar charts specifying left starting points and widths:

```
color = {'A': 'red', 'B': 'green', 'C': 'blue', 'D': 'yellow'}
for s, t, c in list(zip(df.State, df.Time.shift(-1) - df.Time, df.Time))[: -1]:
    bar(left=c, height=0.8, width=t, bottom=0, color=color[s], orientation="horizontal", label=s)
    print(c, t)
legend();
```

[image]

You can also call

```
get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

use better colors, and make this figure less ugly (it's hard to make it *more* ugly).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that uses LineCollection. My dissatisfaction with it is that the LineCollection elements seem scale-invariant (they appear the same width no matter what the y-axis scale is), which makes it hard to manipulate. Because of this shortcoming I think I prefer the bar solution.

[image: Horizontal bar plot with states represented as colors, and lengths of bars representing the duration that state was valid for.]

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(zip([0, 3, 4, 7, 9, 12], ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'A']), 
                  columns=['Time', 'State'])

df['Duration'] = df['Time'].shift(-1) - df['Time']

# Showing how we can use HTML color names
state_to_color_map = {
    'A': 'LightBlue',
    'B': 'gray',
    'C': 'LightPink',
    'D': 'MediumSeaGreen'
}
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
ax = fig.gca()

plot_height = 0  # Can loop this to plot multiple bars

for state, state_color in state_to_color_map.iteritems():
  segments = [[(start, plot_height), (start + duration, plot_height)] for 
              (start, duration) in 
              df[df['State'] == state][['Time', 'Duration']].values]
  plot_segments = mpl.collections.LineCollection(
      segments=segments,
      # In matplotlib 2.2.2, this code is `mcolors.to_rgba(...)`
      # Use this code for matplotlib 1.5.3.
      colors=[mcolors.colorConverter.to_rgba(state_color)] * len(segments),
      linewidths=50)
  ax.add_collection(plot_segments)

ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
ax.set_xlim(0, 12)

# Legend
patches = []
for state, color in sorted(state_to_color_map.iteritems()):
  patches.append(mpatches.Patch(color=color, label=state))
ax.legend(handles=patches, bbox_to_anchor=(1.10, 0.5), loc='center', 
          borderaxespad=0.)
```